# Spark not allowing separate queries on same data sources within same Spark SQL query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's take an example of 2 newly created dataframes empDF and deptDF.
Create a view

```
empDF.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
deptDF.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")

spark.sql("select * from table1 as t1
             join table2 as t2 on (...) where t1.col1 not in 
              (select t3.col2 from table1 as t3)"
         )
```

Surprisingly, run time exception occurs complaining "table1" view or table does not exist. This is happening when two different query is performed on same data source. 
May I have some idea please.

Comment: `This is happening when two different query is performed on same data source` - can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you please add the error as well? It helps to identify the problem.

Comment: @shay__ table1 has been used in the given query 2 time on different condition. This one I have mentioned as different query.

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim During runtime, spark is throwing exception "table1 does not exists". This is happening when same source(table1 in this case) is getting used multiple times in same query based on separate filter criteria.

Comment: No issue running this with Spark 2.4. What version are you running?

Comment: Pls show actual error message.

Comment: Me too using Spark 2.4 with scala 12. Do you mean, it could be a problem of other version. I have changed my code flow entirely, so can't share you the error stack. But it's error of "table or view does not exists named table1".

Comment: I ran it fine, no worries